# Data Flow transformation on json object where each element is a array

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, data-transform

How to convert the following json object:

```
{"IDpol": [406.0, 407.0, 412.0], "ClaimNb": [1, 1, 1], "Exposure": [0.77, 0.07, 0.84], "Area": ["C", "C", "E"], "VehPower": [9, 9, 7], "VehAge": [0, 0, 3], "DrivAge": [29, 29, 40], "BonusMalus": [72, 72, 54], "VehBrand": ["B12", "B12", "B12"], "VehGas": ["Regular", "Regular", "Regular"], "Density": [360, 360, 5746], "Region": ["R91", "R91", "R11"]}
```

In the below given csv using  azure data factory

```
IDpol,ClaimNb,Exposure,Area,VehPower,VehAge,DrivAge,BonusMalus,VehBrand,VehGas,Density,Region
406.0 ,   1   ,  0.77  , C  ,   9    ,   0   ,   29  , 72      ,  B12   ,Regular,360   , R91
407.0 ,   1   ,  0.07  , C  ,    9   ,   0   ,   29  , 72      ,  B12   ,Regular,360   ,R91
412.0 ,   1   ,  0.84  , E  ,    7   ,   3   , 40    , 54      , B12    , Regular,5746, R11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this and able to get the desired result as follows.

For this first use **dataflow to get all arrays as one array of JSON**. Store this result as JSON and then use **copy activity to get the csv file of individual columns**.

Use **Derived column transformation** after source.

create another **temporary column** and give the below dynamic expression.

```
mapIndex(IDpol, @(Idpol=#item,ClaimNb=ClaimNb[#index],Area=Area[#index],BonusMalus=BonusMalus[#index],DrivAge=DrivAge[#index],Exposure=Exposure[#index],Region=Region[#index],VehAge=VehAge[#index],VehBrand=VehBrand[#index],VehPower=VehPower[#index],VehGas=VehGas[#index],Density=Density[#index]))
```

[image]

As length of all arrays are same, the above will give the result as follows.

[image]

Store this in JSON file. In sink settings give output to single file and specify the file name.

You can remove the extra columns in sink mapping as we only want `temp` column.

[image]

You can see the **dataflow output JSON** after Executing this dataflow in pipeline.

[image]

Now, use **copy activity** with the **above JSON as source file** and **CSV** as sink.

Go to **`Mapping`** and click on **`import mapping`**. Use **Advanced editor** and **Collection reference** to do the correct mapping.

[image]

You can mention the type also if you want.

Execute this copy activity and you can get the result CSV like below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was also able to do it later. mapIndex is the key to it. But instead, I used a concat function to concat elements that should be in the same row. And then created different columns using parse transformation and convert it into csv in dataflow itself. But my approach isn't optimized as you and is more costly